# How do I add FadeIn/FadeOut javascript effect during images change after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I have `2` images that changes after a few seconds. I want to add a `FadeIn/FadeOut` effect when these images changes.

```
<script>
    var img_tracker = "icon1";

    function changeImg()
    {
        var pic = document.getElementById("img1");

        if (img_tracker == "icon1") {
            pic.src = "images/icon1.png";
            img_tracker = "icon2.png";
        } else {
            pic.src = "images/icon2.png";
            img_tracker = "icon1";
        }
    }

    setInterval("changeImg()", 2000);
</script>

<img src="images/icon1.png" id="img1">
```

That is my current code, is there any way I can add `fadeOut/fadeIn` on every image change?

Comment: https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery#8.3

Comment: Is there a way to add fadeIn/fadeOut with this **setInterval("changeImg()", 2000);** line of code?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `CSS` transitions. Then, you can `fade-out` the current image periodically with `setInterval()`. Once the image is completely `fade-out` you can change the image source and `fade-in`. To detect the `fade-out` transition you can use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) over the `"transitionend"` event.

## Example:

```js
var img_tracker = "icon1";
var pic = document.getElementById("img1");

function changeImg()
{
    if (img_tracker == "icon1")
    {
        pic.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000";
        img_tracker = "icon2";
    }
    else
    {
        pic.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF";
        img_tracker = "icon1";
    }
}

function fadeIn()
{
    pic.classList.remove("fade-out");
    pic.classList.add("fade-in");    
}

function fadeOut()
{
    pic.classList.remove("fade-in");
    pic.classList.add("fade-out");

    // Add listener to the "transitionend" event.
    
    pic.addEventListener("transitionend", function x()
    {
        // Remove the previously added listener, change
        // the image and fade-in the new image.
        
        pic.removeEventListener("transitionend", x);
        changeImg();
        fadeIn();
    });
}

setInterval(fadeOut, 5000);
```

```css
.fade {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" class="fade">
```

Comment: @Waqqarkhan maybe you need to add listeners to specific vendor for transition end: `webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd`. What is the error you see?

Comment: index.html:55 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
at fadeOut

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Comment: I am trying jquery now as I think it will be more easy to add fade effect but I am unable to target img_tracker. This is my code now

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var img_tracker = "icon1";

   var pic = document.getElementById("img1"); 
   if(img_tracker == "icon1"){
    pic.src = "images/icon1.png";
    img_tracker = "icon2.png";
    $('+img_tracker+').fadeIn(3000);
   }else{
    pic.src = "images/icon2.png";
    img_tracker = "icon1";
    $('+img_tracker+').fadeIn(3000);
   }
  });
 </script>

Comment: You can't do this `$('+img_tracker+').fadeIn(3000);`, since img_tracker will hold `icon2.png` and it is not a selector. You need to `fadeOut` first, then use the `onComplete` callback that you can use as argument of `fadeOut` to change the src attribute and finally `fadeIn()`. You can create a new question for this, if you have issues to get it work.

Comment: Okay, I am going to add a new question for this. Thank you