# smoothly changing backgrounds

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my original project I have the same function like reNewIt() but only with fadeIn() at the begining and it is called after document is loaded, the fadeIn effect (from opacity 0 to 1) is working just fine.

When I tried to make a button to change the background (*first to make opacity 0 then change the image, then make opacity 1*) I see in dev tools opacity is jumping from 1 to 0.98 and it doesnt work. Tried different solutions, but I think there is something I cannot understand with the **setInterval**.
*The idea is first to go full white, then change the img, to hide the loading time of the picture.*

I've read posts and searched Google all day, can't make it work..
I can simply get some other code for that effect, but I really want to make it myself. (*what is the point of copying when I want to learn*)
I'll be very pleased if someone can help me figure it out.

```js
let images = {
img1: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg',
img2: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZGF3bnxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80',
img3: 'https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/4plHDVeTkWuFMihxQnzBSb/aea2f06d675c3d710d095306e377382f/shutterstock_554314555_copy.jpg',
img4: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014__340.jpg'
}




function reNewIt() {
  let opacity = 1;
  let elem = document.getElementById('bgimage');
  let num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);

  fadeOut();
  elem.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images['img'+ num ]})`;
  fadeIn();


  function fadeIn() {
    let id = 0;
    id = setInterval(frameIn, 20);
    function frameIn() {
      opacity += 0.02;
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
  }

  function fadeOut() {
    let id = 0;
    id = setInterval(frameOut, 20);
    function frameOut() {
      opacity -= 0.02;
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#bgimage {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bgimage">
  <button onclick="reNewIt()">Click me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56104389/how-do-i-add-fadein-fadeout-javascript-effect-during-images-change-after-a-few-s

Comment: There are increment and decrement intervals executing simultaneously, competing with each other to change the opacity up and down.  Neither interval ever gets cleared, so that happens forever.

Comment: James - how I can make first to complete the first function then the other?

Answer (score 1):

You can add transition to your css

```js
let images = {
img1: 'https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg',
img2: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZGF3bnxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80',
img3: 'https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/4plHDVeTkWuFMihxQnzBSb/aea2f06d675c3d710d095306e377382f/shutterstock_554314555_copy.jpg',
img4: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014__340.jpg'
}




function reNewIt() {
  let opacity = 1;
  let elem = document.getElementById('bgimage');
  let num = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);

  fadeOut();
  elem.style.backgroundImage = `url(${images['img'+ num ]})`;
  fadeIn();


  function fadeIn() {
    let id = 0;
    id = setInterval(frameIn, 20);
    function frameIn() {
      opacity += 0.02;
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
  }

  function fadeOut() {
    let id = 0;
    id = setInterval(frameOut, 20);
    function frameOut() {
      opacity -= 0.02;
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#bgimage {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color:red;
   transition: 2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bgimage">
  <button onclick="reNewIt()">Click me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Heads up, the transitions don't work in Firefox.